# Process multiple user requests with asp.net mvc async controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have long-working sync controller method, and while it is running, I cannot get answers to other user requests.

I made everything async using async/await and ConfigureAwait(False), but I still need to wait.

Simple example:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var result = await Task.Run(() => Wait()).ConfigureAwait(false); 

        return View(result);
    }

    private async Task<bool> Wait()
    {
        await Task.Delay(60000);

        return true;
    }
```

Now, if I send request to this method "mycontroller/Index", I expect that I can get View for another method "anotherController/Index", but I should wait until async method is completed.

Is it normal behavior? Should I use async to free ui thread and make it available until long-running method is completed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET serializes same-`Session` requests to avoid problems of simultaneous writes to the same `Session` from multiple threads. Actions of controllers marked with session `ReadOnly` attribute will be executed in parallel:

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It helped me so much!